# req.body is empty, why?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I want to send some data to my MongoDB database, but in router.post my req.body is empty, if I use stuff that I put in my send function in `User(req.body)` instead of `req.body data` will be send to my MongoDB database correctly.

This is my router that I use, `router.get` work fine, it return database tables correctly on `/api` page:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("./model/models");
const parser = require("body-parser").json();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const data = await User.find({});
    res.json(data);
});

router.post("/",parser,async (req, res) => {
    console.log('1')
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log('2')
    parser.v
    await User(req.body).save();
    res.json({"msg": "ok"});
});

module.exports = router
```

This is my `index.js` file code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const parser = require("body-parser").json();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.urlencoded(true));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(parser);
app.use('/',require("./routes/routes"))
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'))
app.use("/api", require('./data/api'))

app.listen(5000,function(){
    console.log('server is alive')
})
```

This is function that what I use to send data:

```
const btn1 = document.getElementById('btnEnter')
let Login = "123"
btn1.addEventListener('click' ,e=>{
    send({newsTxT : "someTextHere",newsZag:"someZag",author:"SomeAuthor"})
})
const send = async(body) => {
    let res = await fetch("/api", {
        method: "post",
        header: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    });
    let data = await res.json();
    console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: Since you use `express.json()`, you don't need `body-parser` at all. `body-parser` was deprecated in favor of `express.json()`.

Comment: See these SO posts on [How to use body-parser in express router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985486/how-to-use-body-parser-in-express-router) and [body parser logging empty object in express router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61975632/body-parser-logging-empty-object-in-express-router) for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

The only weird thing I see is that you are using a `json body-parser` and also the `express.json()` both technically do the same, but `body-parser` is deprecated so it might be causing a bug.

Also you don't have to import it again in the routes, placing `app.use(express.json())` at `index.js` will make it work for all endpoints/routes.

See how this refactor goes:

```js
const router = require('express').Router()
const User = require('./model/models')

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await User.find({})
  res.json(data)
})

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('1')
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log('2')
  await User(req.body).save()
  res.json({ 'msg': 'ok' })
})

module.exports = router
```

index.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var path = require('path')

app.use(express.urlencoded(true))
app.use(express.json())

app.use('/', require('./routes/routes'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use('/api', require('./data/api'))

app.listen(5000, function () {
  console.log('server is alive')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked fine:

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const router = express.Router()
router.use(express.json())

app.use(router)

router.post('/api/user', function(req, res) {
    // ...
}
```

I see the difference may be using the: `app.use(router)`

Note that in the above code the statement:

```
router.use(express.json())
```

can be replaced with (using the `body-parser`):

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
router.use(bodyParser.json())
```

This worked fine with `express` version 4.17.1, `body-parser` version 1.19.0 and `NodeJS` version 12.18.3